# Question about array elements and incrementing in C

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
   int i, j, k = 1, m;
   i = ++a[1];
   j = a[1]++;
   m = a[i++];
   printf("\n%d %d %d", i, j, m);

   return 0;
}
```

The output is: 3 2 15.
Why is that? Shouldn't ++a[1] be 2, a[1]++ is 2, and a[i++] should be 20 because it's a at index 3?
So why is the output not 2 2 20.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When `a[i++]` is evaluated, `i` has the value of `2`. So the *value* of this expression is the same as `a[2]`, which is `15`. The *side effect* of this expression is a post-increment of `i`; this side effect will increment `i` to the value of `3` and takes effect *after* the expression-value of `15` got evaluated.